# My texture isnt wrapping my object properly

Tags: modeling, uv, shader-nodes

[image]

So i was doing Cg Geek's satisfying animation tutorial and when i tried to add the texter this happened. It wouldnt wrap all the way

Comment: Ad the texture to the Boolean cutter object as well.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "this happen"? Maybe pack your image and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/